# How can prevent user view the base code of the website and folders tree in sources tab of view option

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms

I have a question that in the picture I have 3 parts that I want to ask.
First in the 2nd area, I want when the user opens the source view option to not show the directory tree like this, which means it will be hidden.
In the 3rd area, how to hide all the javascript code, because I have some javascript files to validate the registration and login form, and the user can edit the condition in this javascript file.
Hope everyone has a way to fix this situation, either encrypting, or hiding, or shuffling the files in the folder so that users can't identify them.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, you cannot do what you are describing. When someone's browser loads HTML, CSS, JS, image files, etc., the browser itself shows the files inside of the "Source" tab of the developer console, and lists files as a tree-styled directory list. If you're doing anything private, such as authentication, SQL queries, etc., you need to use a server.

It sounds like another issue you have is data validation, and the fact that a client can modify the validation rules. In this cases, a server is necessary so that the server can validate the inputs before doing anything with that data.